# Converting PDF to JPEG generates ridiculously large /tmp files (using GMAGICK)

Tags: php, gmagick

So I have a php script that takes a PDF and converts it to JPEG images. Everything was fine until today, but today I got this PDF, that for some reason cause the generation of very large files in my `/tmp` directory (like ~14 gigs, while the PDF file in itself is ~18MB).

Here is the PDF in question:

https://www.ciamarket.lt/sites/default/files//failai/leidinys_01.15-28-compressed.pdf

And here is relevant code:

```
<?php
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36';

    $response = $this
        ->httpClient
        ->request(
            'GET',
            $url,
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'User-Agent' => $userAgent,
                ],
            ]
        );

    $contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    $tmpFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'brochure_s');

    $tmpFile = fopen($tmpFilePath, 'r+');
    fwrite($tmpFile, $contents);

while (true) {
try {
    $image = new \Gmagick();
    $image->setResolution($width, $height);

    $image->readimage($tmpFilePath . '[' . $i . ']');

    $image->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $image->setCompressionQuality(75);
    $image->resizeImage($width, $height, \Gmagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, false);

    $imageBlob = $image->getImageBlob();

    $this
       ->uploader
       ->uploadData(
                        $imageBlob,
                        $brochureId,
                        '',
                        'jpg'
    );

    $image->destroy();
} catch (\Throwable $t) {
    break;
}
}
```

I exctracted the relevant bits from my script.

I think line 28 is responsible for generating the huge file.

Any idea how this could be adressed?

Comment: What $width and $height are you using? I'd try lowering them and see if it makes a difference

Comment: $width  = 1059;
        $height = 1497;

Yeah it does make a difference. But it kind of has to be about this size. But regardless of size... even at these dimensions why would it generate file of this size? I mean what kind of image should take up 14GIGS?

Comment: How many pages does the PDF have? If it has hundreds of pages and Gmagick tries to load the entire file, it could create 14GB worth of data, even at that resolution.

Comment: no... it's like 10 pages.